# How to write a number on a binary file with bash

Tags: bash

I need to write the size of a file in a binary file using bash. But I want it to stay on 4 bytes:
The length of the file is 224128 bytes. So if I do

```
echo -n -e '224128' > output.bin
```

it will compute 6 bytes, but I want it to occupy 4 bytes. How can I do?
I don't know if I made myself clear.

Thank you very much in advance!

Comment: You need to convert `224128` to its binary representation. There's no easy way to do this in bash, it depends on your system's endianness.

Comment: `bash` is not really designed for working with binary data.

Comment: If you convert your number into hex you can write binary hex bytes to the file with `echo -n -e '\x00\x03\x68\x80' >> output.bin`, for example.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Perl to the rescue:

```
perl -we 'print pack "N", shift' 224128
```

To check the output, you can use e.g. `xxd`:

```
$ perl -we 'print pack "N", shift' 224128 | xxd
00000000: 0003 6b80                                ..k.
```

And indeed,

```
$ echo $((16#36b80))
224128
```

If you need different endianness, check [pack](http://p3rl.org/pack).